# How to visualize large dataset ? Such as ucf101, hmdb51?

Tags: dataset, visualize

Nowadays, I want to visualize some video datasets. However, I don't know which tool I should select. Tensorboard ? But I think it can't solve my problem, because it is based on traditional machine learning mathod, such as pca. So is there any more tool for me to visualize large dataset , such as a common video dataset named ucf101, about 6 G ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been building [Sieve](https://sievedata.com/) recently for exactly this. Upload your data and it splits it up into individual frames, tags them with information about the people, objects, and more - and then lets you visualize + export samples super quickly using the dashboard. You can [request access](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSecOGSQEWH1KjPN68zzxV3XtGqxtvinGH-BRzVew2ovD6D49Q/viewform) for an API key for free if it's for personal use.